# Curiosity about a simple identity

Tags: reference-request

Consider the well known formula

$$1^3 + 2^3 +\cdots+ n^3 = (1+\cdots+n)^2  , n \in N$$

Now suppose that for all $n \in N$ the identity is true :

$$1^k + 2^k +\cdots+ n^k = (1+\cdots+n)^{k-1}  $$

with $k \in N$ fixed. Which is the possible values of $k$ ?

Someone could point me a reference?

Sorry for my english, it is not good

Thanks in advance

Comment: $1 + 2^k = 3^k$ so $k=1$

Comment: ops i did a typo, i will fix it. thanks for your commentary

Comment: sorry for the typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dominant term of the left hand side is  $$ \frac{1}{k+1} n^{k+1}.  $$
The right hand side is $$  \left( \frac{n^2 + n}{2} \right)^{k-1},  $$ dominant term
$$ \frac{2}{2^k} n^{2k - 2}.  $$

So $$  k+1 = 2k - 2 $$ and
$$  3 = k $$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case when $n = 2$. Then we have that $1 + 2^k = 3^{k-1}$. By Catalan's Conjecture (Mihăilescu's theorem), we have that $k = 3$ (the theorem basically states that the only two consecutive perfect powers are $2^3$ and $3^2$.)